# Coin toss- expected value.

Tags: random-variables, variance, expected-value

A coin had tossed three times.
Let:
$X$-number of tails
$Y$-number of heads

Find the expected value and variance $Z=XY$

My solution:
$E(Z)=E(XY)= 2 \cdot 1/4 + 3 \cdot 1/4=6/4$
Because,
I know that $ X,Y=0,1,2,3$
so, $Z=2,3$, since $Z=0,1$ doesn't describe three throws.
And:
$E(Z^2)=13/4$

Comment: Not following.  How can $Z=3$?

Comment: You have $Y=3-X$, so $Z=X(3-X)$. This cannot take the value $3$ since $X\in\{0,1,2,3\}$. You **cannot** have $X=1$ and $Y=3$: since $X+Y=3$.

Comment: Right, so $Z=2$ and that's it.

Comment: No.  $Z$ can also be $0$.  Also, if the $\frac14's$ are meant to be probabilities, then I don't understand that either.  They don't add to $1$, for example.

Comment: There's no reason for any confusion here.  There are only $8$ cases and each has probability $\frac 18$.  Just list all of them and do the calculation by hand.

Comment: Ok, Now I know. :)